# how to get the value dynamic buttons in jsp

Tags: jsp

if i have 30 dynamic buttons then how i know which button is click and what is the value of that button:

```
<table align="center" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
                <%
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                %>
                <tr>
                    <%
                        for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
                    %>
                    <td><input type="button" name="b1"value="<%=k%>id=""></td>
                    <%
                        k++;
                    }
                    %>
                </tr>
                <%
                    }
                %>
            </table>
```

Comment: You can add id attribute to each button or just use unique name.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have  errors

1/

```
 <td><input type="button" name="b1" value="<%=k%>  id=""></td>
```

change it to

```
<td><input type="button" name="b1" value="<%=k%>" id=""></td>
```

2/ k where you declare it ? you should declare it before loop

#### then to get the value of the clicked button there is 2 solutions (that I know) :

1/ put your buttons in a form then get the value with servlet

2/ using JAVASCRIPT

> example of solution 1:

change your jsp to

```
<form id="edit" action="MYSERVLET" method="post" >
        <table align="center" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
                <%
                    int k=1;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                %>
                <tr>
                    <%
                        for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
                    %>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="b1"value="<%=k%>" id=""></td>
                    <%
                        k++;
                    }
                    %>
                </tr>
                <%
                    }
                %>
            </table>
            </form>
```

and the servlet :

```
    public class MYSERVLET extends HttpServlet {
   
        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
    
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
    
    String clickedButton= request.getParameter("b1");
    
    request.setAttribute("val", clickedButton);

     request.getRequestDispatcher("test.jsp").forward(request, response); 
    
        }

}
```

and the next jsp (test.jsp) add

```
<h1>VALUE OF BUTTON IS : ${val}</h1>
```

> example of solution 2:

change your input to :

```
<td><input type="submit" name="b1"value="<%=k%>" id="" onclick='f1(this)'></td>
```

and add this script before  tag :

```
<script>
                
                function f1(objButton){  
                alert(objButton.value);
            }
                
                
            </script>
```